# Setting Slicer to cell value

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I have a slicer "Slicer_Item" that controls "PivotTable1".  Depending on other slicers' selections this slicer has between 1 and 100+ items. When there are so many items it becomes hard to find what you want to select.

**I want to be able to type the items I want, separated by commas, into a cell and have the slicer automatically select those items.**  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Item].&[" & Worksheets("Forecasting").Range("B2") & "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that constructs your array of slicer items and pass that back to a calling macro.

```
Sub slice_away()

    With ActiveWorkbook
        With .Worksheets("Forecasting")
            .SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").VisibleSlicerItemsList = _
                (build_Slicer_Items(.Range("B2:B" & .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)))
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function build_Slicer_Items(rng As Range)
    Dim e As Long, aITMs() As String, itm As Range

    ReDim aITMs(1 To 1)
    For Each itm In rng
        e = e + 1
        ReDim Preserve aITMs(1 To e)
        aITMs(e) = "[Item].&[" & itm.Value2 & "]"
    Next itm

    build_Slicer_Items = aITMs

End Function
```

This compiles but is untested on data. Note that the function is wrapped in brackets. When passing arrays stored as variables into certain calling commands as parameters, the array is generally not identified as an array without a set of wrapping brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense but does throws a Run Time Error 438.  I wonder if my MDX naming is wrong?  I tried simplifying things by just doing one item like .SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").VisibleSlicerItemsList = "[Item].&[baseball] but that threw the same error.  "baseball" does exist in the slicer.